# Python video is not playing Downloaded by using requests module

Tags: python, django, django-views, python-requests, python-requests-html

I'm working on a Python(3.6) & Django(2) project in which I need to download a video from a URL.
Here's what I have tried:

**from views.py:**

```
    if validation is True:
        url = request.POST.get('video_url')
        r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
        file = open('my_video.mp4', 'wb').write(r.content)
        rea_response = HttpResponse(file, content_type='video/mp4')
        rea_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=my_video.mp4'
        return rea_response
```

The URL from where it's downloading the vide is:

> https://expirebox.com/files/386713962c5f8b7556bc77c4a6c2a576.mp4

It downloads a file with the name as `my_video.mp4` but when I try to open this video it's not playing.

What can be wrong here with my code?
OR is there any better way to download the video from URL.

Comment: That site redirects to an `.html` file first with a button to download the file. They must be doing extra checks (such as referrer, cookies etc).

Comment: Here's I'm providing a direct URL to the video, if I open this URL in the browser it will download the video file.

Comment: That's probably because you have visited the page before. When I click it it takes me to a web page. You should simulate the same behaviour using requests. Scraping is hard.

Comment: So, is there any way to download this video?