# Python Urllib download the video but it's not playable

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, urllib, urllib3

I'm trying to download a video from s URL using Python's urllib package. My Python version is 3.6.

Here's what I have tried:
**from views.py:**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = VideoConverterSerializer(data=self.request.data)
    validation = serializer.is_valid()
    print(serializer.errors)
    if validation is True:
        url = request.POST.get('video_url')
        try:
            r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            with open('my_video.mp4', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.read())
            rea_response = HttpResponse('my_video.mp4', content_type='video/mp4')
            rea_response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=my_video.mp4'
            return rea_response
        except TimeoutError:
            return HttpResponse(TimeoutError)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Not a valid request')
```

Here's an example URL I'm trying with:

> https://expirebox.com/files/386713962c5f8b7556bc77c4a6c2a576.mp4

The code above download the video file as `my_video.mp4` but the video is not playable. The actual size of the video is `~5.9 MB` but the size of download video is `11 KB` only, so definitely something wrong with the downloaded video.

What can be wrong here?

help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python video is not playing Downloaded by using requests module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52417686/python-video-is-not-playing-downloaded-by-using-requests-module)

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually include the video file in your response; you simply create an HttpResponse with the literal text 'my_video.mp4'.

Rather than reading into a file and then trying to pass that file in the response, you should probably use an in-memory buffer:

```
from io import BytesIO
...
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = BytesIO(r.read())
rea_response = HttpResponse(data, content_type='video/mp4')
```

However, you should note that your URL appears to point to an HTML page, not a video file.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, so can we downlaod a video from a URL which is not a direct url?

Comment: I don't really understand your question.

Comment: I mean, as I haven't a direct url of my video and I have tried your code but the returned video is still not playable.

Comment: You need to put it somewhere it can actually be downloaded from. Amazon S3 is perfect for this sort of thing.

Comment: Let me try to setup aws S3.

Comment: Now i'm trying this url `https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/vcapi/ImgSeg.mp4` but it returns 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Hi @Daniel Roseman, Now it starts downloading the video but this time it's taking too much time, I think it ~6 minutes here but the video is still downloading.

Comment: @AbdulRehman I just use your link with no downloading time problem. And I have a crappy internet.